# HWND coming up NULL

Tags: c++, windows

The code Im running:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const auto pClassName = "direct3D";

    //register window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = nullptr;
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;
    wc.lpszMenuName = pClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = nullptr;        
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    //create instance of window
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        pClassName, 
        "Direct3D", 
        WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU, 
        0, 0, 640, 480, 
        nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr 
    );
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);


    //message pump

    MSG msg;
    int test = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:
A simple window that I can drag around, minimize, or close.

Errors:
No errors being printed.
But stepping through shows this for the value of hwnd:[image: hwnd coming up NULL and a read error]. I am guessing it has something to do with this. I looked through MSDN documents pertaining to the error but nothing helpful. I am following a tutorial for Directx3d on YouTube.

Comment: When a Win32 function fails, you should call `GetLastError()` to get the reason. Can you post what this function returns?

Comment: Naturally, you should check the return value of `RegisterClassEx()` in case this is the function that actually fails.

Comment: And in case it isn't, iust check the return value of _every_ Windows API function. Why ask a human if the computer can automatically tell you what's wrong?

Comment: @rodrigo I got error ID 1400 - I looked it up and its a invalid window handle error. I will look into it. Thanks for your help this is my first day with Windows API.

Answer (score 8):

You are not giving your Window class a name, that is the member `lpszClassName`. Instead you are setting `lpszMenuName` which is surely not what you want.

PS: You say: *"No errors being printed"*. Indeed, Win32 does not print errors, it is your responsibility to always check the return value of Win32 function calls (`RegisterClassEx()` returns `0` on error). Then, if it fails, call `GetLastError()` to get the reason. You can get the list of available reasons [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/ms681381(v=vs.120)). And if you want, you can now print the error message (see [FormatMessage()](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/ms679351(v=vs.120))) in the debug window, stderr, your log file...

As you probably noticed, tutorials in the Internet usually omit error handling because it is boring and adds noise to the thing they want to teach. But in the real world, proper error checking is always the best idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your suggestion of using "GetLastError()" was very helpful. I am new with the API and did not know these things. Im learning a lot! This is exciting! :D